# How to prove that this infinite product equals 4

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

This question is from Ponnusamy and Silvermann's complex variables with applications Ch- 12 , subsection Infinite products.

> Question Prove that $\prod_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^2-1}{n^3-4} =4$.

I think there is a typo in the question as degree of denominator is 1 more than degree of numerator.So, for n large the product will be equal to 0.

So, I am requesting you to  verify.

In case I am wrong kindly tel me my mistake and right way to solve it.

Comment: you r right should have been $n^2-4$,its easy afterwards

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Solved it for $n^2 -4$ and got 4 as answer. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help ,you could also use logarithms and telecopic summing oo